# Multi-level drop down menu has toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone please help me solve a toggle issue in my drop down menu? I have slowed the animation just for viewing purposes.

Here is my multi-level drop down menu (test page only). If you click/tap on a second-level option ("Border", "Zipper", "Dress Shirt", etc., you will see the problem--the function starts to open the third level menu, but also closes the second-level menu.

Here is the basic function I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#dropmenu li:has(div)").click(function () {
    $('#dropmenu li.top-level > #dropmenu li.top-level div.drop_6col-bottom').not($(this).children("#dropmenu li.top-level div.drop_6col-bottom").slideToggle(400)).hide();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).children('div').hide();
});
});
```

Second level function is the same, except every instance of "top-level" becomes "second-level"

What am I doing wrong?? (Yes, I have searched exhaustively for an answer, but it isn't quite clicking.)

Comment: Try to use event.stopPropagation() I think you event firing twice. but you need to add argument event in your function

Comment: How do I do this? Sorry, far from jQuery savvy, but working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the beginning

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#dropmenu li:has(div)").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#dropmenu li.top-level > #dropmenu li.top-level div.drop_6col-bottom').not($(this).children("#dropmenu li.top-level div.drop_6col-bottom").slideToggle(400)).hide();
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).children('div').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like that did it! Thank you so much! I figured simple solution, I was missing forest for trees. Again, thanks!!